# Highlighting Text in WP7 Databound Listbox

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7

I am attempting to highlight text in a databound ListBox and highlight matching strings exactly like the email application on Windows Phone 7.

The search button pulls up a Popup, and on the TextChanged event, I'm filtering from a master list and re-setting the DataContext:

```
private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
  results = allContent.Where(
    x => x.Content.Contains(txtSearch.Text)
  ).ToList();

  DataContext = results;
}
```

That part works great.  The problem is with highlighting the matched text.  I've tried iterating over the ListBoxItems in various events (Loaded, ItemsChanged) but they're always empty.

Any ideas about how text highlighting might be done in a databound ListItem's child TextBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution that I went with:

```
private void ResultsText_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var textBlock = sender as TextBlock;
    if (txtSearch.Text.Length > 0 && textBlock.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        BoldText(ref textBlock, txtSearch.Text, Color.FromArgb(255, 254, 247, 71));
    }
}

public static void BoldText(ref TextBlock tb, string partToBold, Color color)
{
    string Text = tb.Text;
    tb.Inlines.Clear();

    Run r = new Run();
    r.Text = Text.Substring(0, Text.IndexOf(partToBold));
    tb.Inlines.Add(r);

    r = new Run();
    r.Text = partToBold;
    r.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
    r.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(color);
    tb.Inlines.Add(r);

    r = new Run();
    r.Text = Text.Substring(Text.IndexOf(partToBold) + partToBold.Length, Text.Length - (Text.IndexOf(partToBold) + partToBold.Length));
    tb.Inlines.Add(r);
}
```