# wp7 ObservableCollection filter texbox input and highlight result

Tags: windows-phone-7, filtering, observablecollection

I have been looking for a way to do this for a while.
What I have is a textbox and on textchanged event I want it to filter as you type and highlight parts of the result as when you search in the people's hub.
.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: I tried to make as in this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479033/highlighting-text-in-wp7-databound-listbox but this was before I understood that I was wrong. I have the code that he has but I tried to make it for my viewmodel. So the changed event looks like this App.ViewModel.AllToDoItems.Where(x => x.ItemDriver.Contains(valueSearch.Text)).ToList(); what's happen is that my observable collection AllToDoItems goes blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> SearchResult 
                  { 
               get {return //...} 
               set {//set an raise property changed event}
                 }
private list <Item> _allItems = //populate items list here
```

In `textChanged` event handler do the following:

```
 var filteredList = _allItems.Where(item.TextPropetry.Contains(enteredText))
                    .ToList();
 SearchResult = new ObservableCollection<Item>(filteredList);
```

That is about filtering.

The way to hilight depends on you UI implementation.

upd:

```
 Color currentAccentColorHex = 
        (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"];
```

More about colors [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769545%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

Comment: Now i may done some wrong here because nothing happen so missed something or misunderstood can be an option. I have my AllItems collection in my ViewModel and also my SearchResult collection. Then i have in the textChanged event the following.

var filteredList = App.ViewModel.AllToDoItems.Where(x => x.ItemDriver.Contains(valueSearch.Text));
            App.ViewModel.SearchResult = new ObservableCollection<ToDoItem>(filteredList);

Comment: does your ViewModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Comment: Yes it does, something more I can answer to get to the bottom of the problem

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint to the textChanged event handler (press F9)? Does the programm stop there? Also put the breackpoint into get line of SearchResult and check is there any items in *value*?

Comment: For the textChanged event handler there is now problem what i can see but for the get line for SearchResult i get this:

SearchResult = Could not evaluate expression

Comment: For debug add .ToList() call as I did in my answer. And look at the getter in a debugger again. Is value empty?

Comment: And not get, but set line. My mistake, sorry. We want to check if filtered list empty or not.

Comment: Now its working with the filtering now its just the highlighting left.

Comment: The highlighting is working now two. Thanks alot for the help.

Comment: highlighitingpublic static void BoldText(ref TextBlock tb, string partToBold, Color color) 
{ 
    string Text = tb.Text; 
    tb.Inlines.Clear(); 
 
    Run r = new Run(); 
    r.Text = Text.Substring(0, Text.IndexOf(partToBold)); 
    tb.Inlines.Add(r); 
 
    r = new Run(); 
    r.Text = partToBold; 
    r.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold; 
    r.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(color); 
    tb.Inlines.Add(r); 
 
    r = new Run(); 
    r.Text = Text.Substring(Text.IndexOf(partToBold) + partToBold.Length, Text.Length - (Text.IndexOf(partToBold) + partToBold.Length)); 
    tb.Inlines.Add(r); 
}

Comment: highlighiting done like in the link herr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479033/highlighting-text-in-wp7-databound-listbox , how do i set the color to be phoneaccentbrush instead of yhellow as it is now